# Using lists to check usernames and passwords

Tags: python

**I'm not sure why this code isn't working. I have the error TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable** I need the code to check the usernames and passwords from two different lists, and if the username and password match spots in the list and are correct, the user is "granted access."

```
#Part 1: Opening the files and grabbing data
filename1 = "c:\\Users\\Anna Hamelin\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\SourceCode\\Project2\\usernames.txt"
file = open(filename1, "r")

#Usernames
users = file.read()
usernameslist = [line.strip() for line in open("c:\\Users\\Anna Hamelin\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\SourceCode\\Project2\\usernames.txt")]
print(users)                #Check file
print(usernameslist)       #Check usernames list

filename2 = "c:\\Users\\Anna Hamelin\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\SourceCode\\Project2\\passwords.txt"
file = open(filename2, "r")

#Passwords
passwords = file.read()
passwordslist = [line.strip() for line in open("c:\\Users\\Anna Hamelin\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\SourceCode\\Project2\\passwords.txt")]
print(passwords)            #Check file
print(passwordslist)       #Check passwords list

#Compile the usernames and passwords lists for easy checking
compiled_list = list(zip(usernameslist,passwordslist))
print(compiled_list)

#Scores
filename3 = "c:\\Users\\Anna Hamelin\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\SourceCode\\Project2\\scores.txt"
file = open(filename3, "r")

scores = file.read()
scoreslist = [line.strip() for line in open("c:\\Users\\Anna Hamelin\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\SourceCode\\Project2\\scores.txt")]
print(scores)           #Check file
print(scoreslist)       #Check scores

def login():
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")  
    for i in range(len(usernameslist)):
        if username == i and password == [i]:
            print("Access granted!")
        else:
            print("Incorrect Login credentials, please try again.")


login()
```

Comment: Is it not returning anything or not printing anything? For the function to return it needs a return statement

Comment: There is no return statement in the login function (literally), so it is not returning anything. It is also not called anywhere, so it is not even running.

Comment: Of course the function doesn't return anything - you never tell it to. You need to put `return [whatever you want to return]` at the end of your function (or elsewhere in it) in order for it to return something.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I don't think they want to return, by the looks of it they are going to write logic where "Access granted" goes. There are other logical errors as well that I think are why it's not working.

Comment: @user I fixed the list but the function is still not working. Can you help me? I am new to coding

Comment: Ah. In login() you've added j but removed the thing about iterating through j.

Replace the line:

`if username == i and password == [j]:` with `if username == i and password == [i]:` and I think it will work. I've added the whole new `login()` function to my answer.

Comment: @user now I have the error code mentioned above. How can I fix it?

Comment: @AnnaHamelin do you mean you are getting "Incorrect Login credentials, please try again."? If so, you'll need to go through and reorder the lists so the usernames match up with the passwords, I don't see how else this could fail unless the code to retrieve the lists comes up blank.

Comment: @user I am seeing the message: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @AnnaHamelin Oh. I made a mistake in this line (long time since python.) Replace `for i in len(usernameslist)` with `for i in range(len(usernameslist))` I'll replace it on my answer as well.

Comment: @user This time, I ran it and entered a correct username and password  and got "Incorrect Login credentials, please try again.
Incorrect Login credentials, please try again.
Incorrect Login credentials, please try again.
Incorrect Login credentials, please try again.
Incorrect Login credentials, please try again."

Comment: @AnnaHamelin Multiple... times? Odd. Try replacing `if username == i and password == [i]` with `if username == i and password == i`, as it is showing `password` as an index of a list.

Comment: @user the same problem occurred

Comment: @AnnaHamelin Okay. This must mean that the data is corrupted. What I would recommend is making a backup of the username and password files. Then, get rid of all passwords and usernames except 1 pair and check if they work. Make sure that the `users` and `passwords` are also actually filled with data and the retrieval commands actually work.

I think this is as far StackOverflow can help you programmatically as now it's to do with the system and retrieving data. I'd gratefully appreciate if you would accept my answer with the green tick if you feel it is satisfactory :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `login()`, you are using `i` as an iterator within itself.

```
def login():
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")  
    for i in [usernameslist]:
        if username == [i]:
            for j in [passwordslist]:
                if password == [j]:
                    return "Access granted!"
                else:
                    return "Incorrect Login credentials, please try again."
        else:
            return "Incorrect Login credentials, please try again."
```

This above should find the password and work with your logic.
However, shouldn't you be using the specific username for the password? This is checking if the username and the password are available, not whether the password matches the username. As you are looping through password and username **separately**, you would simply check if someone has the password and someone has the username, whether it is the same person or not. If so, replace with this:

```
def login():
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")  
    for i in range(len(usernameslist)):
        if username == i and password == j:
            return "Access granted!"
        else:
            return "Incorrect Login credentials, please try again."
```

Make sure with this that the usernames and passwords are ordered the same within both lists. Or, I'd recommend storing a **2D list** looking something like this:

`list = [["Annie","password1"],["bob","wordpass39"]]` where the first entry is the username and second is the password.

**Edit:** with the fixed `login()` function you should now do this:

```
def login():
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")  
    for i in range(len(usernameslist)):
        if username == i and password == i:
            print("Access granted!")
        else:
            print("Incorrect Login credentials, please try again.")
```

Comment: The username and password are not being requested when I run the program...any ideas?

Comment: Ah. You aren't calling `login()`. Just add `login()` on its own at the very end of your program and it should work.